# Find a sequence of RV s.t. $X_n \to 0$ in prob. but its Variance does not?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, probability-limit-theorems

Find $X_n$ such that $Var(X_n)\to \infty$ but $X_n \to 0$ in probability. I have found a similar example where the expectation runs to infinity but the actual random variable converges to $0$. However, I can't think of an example where my question is satisfied.

Define $X_n = Z_n X_{n-1}$ where the $Z_n's$ are IID and have probability mass function:
\begin{align} 
Z_n = \begin{cases} 1/3 & z = 3\\
2/3 & z = 1/3 \end{cases}
\end{align}

Assume that $X_0 = 1$. Then, $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]\mathbb{E}[Z_n]$

But if I work it out then $\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]$ is similarly defined as $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ and we end up iterating the identity $n$ times but the expectation of $Z_n$ remains the same until we reach $\mathbb{E}[X_0] = 100$. The expectation of $Z_n$ is:
\begin{align}
1/3\times 3 + 2/3 \times 1/3 = 11/9
\end{align}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X_n] = \frac{11}{9}^n
\end{align}
and this goes to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ since we are raising a number larger than $1$ to an infinite power.

However, we can prove the random variable $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

Comment: Hint: Try some two-valued random variables $X_n$, say $P(X_n=0)+P(X_n=n)=1$.

Comment: Take the square root of your example.

Comment: Could you please write down your example?

Comment: Thank you guys. I understand both tips and they work!

Comment: @air I just wrote it down in my post.

Comment: @Did, could you critique my example of a random variable who's expectation runs to infinity but the actual random variable does not?

Comment: "but my computer is dying and I have to start walking soon and can only respond on my phone." Let us wait that your computer resuscitates and that you comfortably complete your question and then we will see.

Comment: @Did I'm back! Day didn't turn out how I thought it would.